# passing params of a nested attribute in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters

I have a form in which there are 'nested attributes' which I am trying to save. I only learnt of these this afternoon and I am new to Rails so I'll try explain this as best as I can.

I have two models, Gallery & Exibition Photos. The former 'has_many' and the latter 'belongs_to' one another. 'exhibition photos' are uploaded via the gallery controller.

I can submit the form however the nested attribute(images) are not being saved at all.

Here is the controller in question

```
def update
  @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]

  if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
     redirect_to '/'
  else
     render '/new'
  end
end

def edit
  @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
end

private
def gallery_params 
  params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, exhibition_images: [:image])

end
```

the reason why it is update and edit rather than new is because an instance of the Gallery model is created when its parent model is created.

here is the edit form

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@gallery, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-10") do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>    

  <%= f.fields_for :exhibition_images do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :exhibition_image, help: "Ensure images are minimum 400x400px"  %>
  <% end %>
 <%= f.submit "Create/Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Gallery model

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  belongs_to :guide
  has_many :exhibition_images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exhibition_images
```

Exhibiton model

```
class ExhibitionImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "100x100", guide: "500x500" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

end
```

Now I am sure there is a much better, cleaner way of doing this which I would appreciate if someone could explain or show. But most of all, I'd like to get this thing working.

update

added dev log

```
Started PATCH "/galleries/martin-bates-geoff-brindle" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-01 00:27:48 +0100
Processing by GalleriesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JzFnQgV4ZBoh176xdphPtH/AJsm/BE1N+LWtTUTOgx8=", "gallery"=>{"title"=>"BLAH BLAH BLAH", "exhibition_images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000104355c28 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ns/ry6z7jfd6qg6j8xr2q6dw0yc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140701-28390-1lfmco8>, @original_filename="oasis.gif", @content_type="image/gif", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[exhibition_images_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"oasis.gif\"\r\nContent-Type: image/gif\r\n">}}}, "commit"=>"Create/Update", "id"=>"martin-bates-geoff-brindle"}
  Guide Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "guides".* FROM "guides"  WHERE (date_starting > '2014-06-30 23:27:48.391845')  ORDER BY "guides"."date_starting" ASC
  Course Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "courses".* FROM "courses"   ORDER BY "courses"."id" DESC LIMIT 2
  YearlyGuide Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "yearly_guides".* FROM "yearly_guides"   ORDER BY "yearly_guides"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Gallery Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "galleries".* FROM "galleries"  WHERE "galleries"."slug" = 'martin-bates-geoff-brindle'  ORDER BY "galleries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: exhibition_images_attributes
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:5000/
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Paperclip, use `image` not `exibition_image`

```
<%= f.file_field :image, help: "Ensure images are minimum 400x400px"  %>
```

Comment: You'll also need to make sure the form is multi-part.  Add `:html => {:multipart => true}` to the bootstrap_form_for.

Comment: still no dice - <%= bootstrap_form_for(@gallery, :html => {:multipart => true}, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-10") do |f| %>

Comment: Look in your development log `tail -f log/development.log` and see what is generated when you click the submit button.  Is everything being submitted correctly from the form?

Comment: Another thing - you can't reuse the 'f' variable.  Use another one for the fields for.  Your making every mistake you can make! :)  I made them all at one point, too.

Comment: posted log, haha thanks dude. I know - I am trying not to dispair!

Comment: I don't think that's the right log?  We're looking for POST "/galleries" - Processing by GalleriesController

Comment: See this line?  `Unpermitted parameters: exhibition_images_attributes`, you'll need to allow it.  Do you have attr_accessible declared?  Add `exhibition_images_attributes`